# How do I change the extension of multiple files in Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

How do I change the extension of multiple files in GCP's Cloud Storage?

For example, in the following directory:

```
gs://[bucket-name]/filesdirectory/
```

I want to change the files with extension **.ipynb** to **.py**.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) which you can install on your local machine or use directly from cloud shell.

gsutil uses command much similar to the linux CLI, you can use the gsutil mv command to achieve this, but since you can't use wildcards there you have to use something similar to this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
gsutil ls gs://your-bucket/*.ipynb| while read x; do gsutil mv $x $(echo $x | sed "s/.ipynb/.py/g"); done
```

I'm not a shell expert so probably this can be improved, but here's an explanation:

- gsutil ls uses a wildcard to return the files you want to rename
- loop through the file and store into a variable the result
- use gsutil mv + sed to place the file extension and rewrite the file as desired

This is like "rewriting" the files entirely since gcs objects are immutable, so there are probably a few considerations that you should keep in mind, although this might not be your case:

- if you have ACLs rules specified for those files, you have to use the
  -p flag to pass them on to the new files
- these are operations for GCS, implying costs based on your storage class. (since mv is actually copy + delete, if you are on
  nearline or coldline, you could have additional early deletion fees)

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#rename), you can rename your files in your GCS buckets using Console, GSutil command, Code or REST APIS.

The Gsutil command you should use is the following:

```
gsutil mv gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OLD_OBJECT_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[NEW_OBJECT_NAME]
```

Furthermore, in case you want to change more than one file, I would suggest you to use a script in order to do it for each file you need to change.

Comment: am aware of the above command, i need change for multiple files..

Comment: as you mentioned script if you are aware of any such script which can i use please do let me know

Comment: You can use the Cloud Storage library, and loop for all the files you want to rename. You can check how to rename the files using Python [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client/storage_move_file.py). 
If you want to use other languages as C++, Node.JS, Java... You can check the samples in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#rename) I shared with you before.
Keep in mind that if you have lot of files, this process could take a while.